# CSS ::after selector animates slower

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

so i have a dropdown menu that will fade in once a link is clicked. once the link is clicked everything is fine the menu fades in but once i click off and a function runs that fades out the dropdown. the triangle that is on top of the box fades out slightly slower than the actual box. in css i have made this triangle with the `:after` selector and a fiddle can be found [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsQXt/2/)

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="Header-Link Right Account-Actions"><?php echo 'Welcome ' . $user->data()->fname . '!'; ?></a>
        <div class="Account-Links">
            <a href="#" class="Account-Link">My Account</a>
            <a href="logout.php" class="Account-Link">Sign Out</a>
            <a href="#" class="Account-Link">Help</a>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.Account-Actions {
    postition: relative;
}

.Account-Links {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.Account-Links-On {
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.Account-Links::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: -8px;
    right: 22px;
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 8px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    border-left: solid 8px transparent;
    border-right: solid 8px transparent;
}

.Account-Link {
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}

.Account-Link:hover {
    background-color: rgba(231,76,60,.75);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.Header-Link {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0 8px;
    line-height: 47px;
    color: #777;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

a.Header-Link:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.Account-Actions').bind('click', function(){
            $('.Account-Links').toggleClass('Account-Links-On');
        });

        $('html').click(function() {
            $('.Account-Links').removeClass('Account-Links-On');
        });

        $('.Account-Links, .Account-Actions').click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created that arrow on different `class` and toggling the opacity on other `class`. You arrow shouldn't be on `.Account-Links`. It should be on `.Account-Links-On` if you don't want that delay to happen.

**[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LsQXt/4/)**

```
.Account-Links-On::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  right: 22px;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 8px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  border-left: solid 8px transparent;
  border-right: solid 8px transparent;
}
```

**And this concludes that :after psuedo selector doesn't animate slower.**